# How to check that a value exists in the group, and the other isn't?

Tags: mysql

I want to check if one value of column exist in group and other isn't. My table looks like this:

```
num | text | 
 1  |    A | 
 1  |    B | 
 2  |    A | 
 2  |    C | 
 3  |    A | 
 3  |    D | 
 4  |    B | 
 4  |    C |
```

I want to get groups with 2,3 num.Now I use this query:

```
select c1.num from table c1 inner join table c2 on c1.num =  c2.num
where c2.text !='B' and c1.type !='B'
group by c1.num, c1.text
having(c1.text='A');
```

Comment: group by is for aggregate function like count or max ... what you mean "I want to check if one value of column exist in group and other isn't. "?  you mean if these value are in a set? and other are not? show the result you want  obtain too

Comment: I want receive groups - group by num, where value of column 'text' is equals 'A' and any other without 'B'. Result should be: 2, 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would put both conditions in the `HAVING` clause, in combination with a `CASE WHEN` construct:

```
select   num 
from     table
group by num
having   max(case text 
               when 'A' then 1 
               when 'B' then 2
             end) = 1
```

Or put in another way:

```
select   num 
from     table
group by num
having   max(case when text='A' then 1 else 0 end) = 1
and      max(case when text='B' then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

This method could be more efficient than a query where the table is selected twice (subquery or join)

Answer (score 0):

I have tried with a subselect

```
select c1.num from table as c1 
where c1.text ='A'
and c1.num not in (select num from table where text='B');
```